# Batch file variables confused with string

Tags: batch-file, text

I am currently trying to store a certain line of a text file in a batch file with this code.

```
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (files.txt) do (
set /a N+=1
set v[!N!]=%%a
)

set /p id="Please choose a number(1-10):"

set number=%v[id]%

echo %number%

endlocal
```

However instead of printing out the line it prints out

```
id
```

Could someone help with this?

Comment: Change this line: `set number=%v[id]%` by this one: `set number=!v[%id%]!`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Like what [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) said I    changed the line

```
set number=%v[id]%
```

by this one

```
set number=!v[%id%]!
```

and it worked